# How do you beat Subway Surfers?

Tags: subway-surfers

Is there a way to beat Subway Surfers for the Kindle Fire, or is it like Temple Run where it goes on forever?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll never beat it, it's endless like Temple Run.

In the words of the great Clevland Brown:

### You never win, you just do a little better every time.

Comment: You can max out the power-ups, unlock all characters, skins, boards and trophies, but never is there a definite end to it.

Answer (score -4):

There is an end to temple run and subway surfers too my friend and I won them both it takes for ever though you have to practice a lot first then you go and you run and there ends up being a little power up that makes it possible to pace all the obsticals then there is no more for subway surfers anyway

Comment: Do you have any proof for this?